# Is this Ferrous Chloride powder?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I recently ordered a 500g sample of Ferrous Chloride powder. However the powder is in light brown color, and on dissolving it in water, it gives a similar brown hue and it is not a clear solution. From what I saw on various preparation methods on YouTube, all the solutions are green in color. Is there something wrong with my sample? Could this be due to Iron Oxide formation? Kindly help.

[image]

Comment: Does it do the same if dissolved in water acidified by HCl ? Is possible it is ferric chloride(III) by packing mistake, or got oxidized ? Interesting result could be provided by analysis of Fe(III) content.

Comment: That powder could be Fe II but the solution not. The latter seems to scatter a lot....